# CRON job autostart validation

Tags: cron, raspbian

[DDNS update](https://www.duckdns.org/install.jsp) is performed from the script duck.sh:

```
chmod 700 duck.sh
```

Open the crontab editor

```
crontab -e
```

A `cron` process runs the script at 5 minute intervals

```
*/5 * * * * ~/duckdns/duck.sh >/dev/null 2>&1
```

restart the cron service:

```
sudo service cron start
```

Can I expect that @startup: the [Raspbian device](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/usage/cron.md) will execute the duck.sh cron job at boot? Or are other steps necessary to ensure that the cron job is activated on @reboot?

How can `ps` or `pgrep` (or any other command) verify that the cron job is active?

Answer (score 1):

You can verify that with `ps -aux | grep duck.sh` if process is running
or you can see just cron jobs in syslog file by running

`grep CRON /var/log/syslog`